# Maintaining modules/macros in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Hey guys I've written a little module/macro that helps our inventory department, they will need to run the module/macro a few times every month. They receive the databases from out in the field these are exported from some 3rd party inventory tracking system we have.

My question, is there any way to install this module/macro outside of the db file but still within access so that the inventory management team does not have to open vb editor, import the module, create a new macro, name it, set it up properly to execute the function?

The module/macro does not need to be changed for any new database that comes in.

Basically they need to be able to open any database received by the field and have this functionality in the module/macro available to them without having to set this. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it a code module or a macro? What does it do? It's not really possible to answer your question without answer to those questions (though I guess someone might accidentally guess the right answer).

Comment: It's a code module and a macro that calls the code.

Comment: Well, not all that helpful an answer from you, since you left out the most important part which is WHAT DOES IT DO? Help us help you out by giving us information. I for one won't be asking a 3rd time...

Comment: David sorry for being vague, it exports rows from a single table into a semi-colon delimited file... They need this file to import into another program to keep track of inventory counts.

Comment: What is it that is dynamic that requires them to import the code/macro into their database?

Comment: David, the database file, each month the people in the field send in a new database file of the current inventory count. They use a third party inventory tracking software that exports the counts to access. We then run the macro to export another file in a semi-colon delimited csv that is them imported into another different inventory tracking software.

Comment: If all that changes is the data tables, then you could create an Access front end that when you open it, it asks you to point to the new data file, then automatically runs the queries on that data file. There are a number of ways to accomplish that (relinking tables, or executing SQL dynamically with IN statements in the FROM clauses, or doing it all in code, etc.), but none require importing anything. This is exactly what I suspected from the beginning, and you could have had this as a solutoin days ago had you provided sufficient information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at my article for vb123.com:

[Using Database Library Files in Your Access Application](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/07_access/libraries.htm)

The thinking there is that you can put access objects in a library file (still an mdb or mde file, or any of the new access file types) and then by just adding a reference to the file in your VBE project, you get that functionality made available to you.

It works with forms, reports, queries, classes, etc.  To be honest, I haven't tried it with macros, but don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

The beauty is that reusable functionality is packaged into one file, that is still just a plain old access file.

If you had the inclination, you could also write an access add in that basically calls your macro in the library.

We did this with a product for making dealing with SQL much easier in Access, and it has worked for years with Access installations all over the world.  You can install the add in using a professional installation package such as wise installation, making it a pretty seamless experience for the end user of your macro.  However, there is a considerable overhead in writing this kind of setup in a professional way.  Depends on what your users need, I suppose.

Comment: thanks for your help! and I will definitely read your article.

Comment: I doubt this is the most obvious way to do this. If you're just running the stuff on different data tables, it would make more sense to put the relevant code/macros in a front-end database and just change the data tables it points to, rather than mucking about with all the difficulties that come with building a library database or add-in. But we don't have enough detail to know.

Comment: David:  fair comment, but note that you don't need an addin, and the library can be just a plain old mdb.  The reason I mentioned this method is that the question mentions that he wants to minimize the effort required from the inventory management team.  I agree with your comment about the hassle, so marked your post up.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are thinking of VBScript or a back-end, front-end set up?

You can use VBScript to perform actions on an Access database, through the Access object, with ADO and so on. The script can either accept command line input, request information, or run against any database in the current directory.

With back-end front-end, the new database becomes the back-end and the Access file with your macro is the front-end. Your macro should ask the user for the name of the back-end file and either use that with the Access object or link the tables, according to what is needed to be done.